# How to style a GWT CaptionPanel?

Tags: css, gwt

Some other CSS files removed the border around all GWT CaptionPanels. Now I'm looking for a way to add the CaptionPanels border again through the GWT projects .css file. Do you have an idea how to do it? Simply adding a .gwt-CaptionPanel{} to the css file has no effect...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm answering my own question here. 
It took me some time to figure out that GWTs CaptionPanel uses a fieldset under the hood. The following places a red 1 pixel solid border around GWT CaptionPaneles:

```
fieldset {
    border: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #ff0000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not experienced with GWT CaptionPanels but you can try to set an !important on the class that makes the borders in the main style sheet. So you get something like: `.borders {border-width:1px !important}`

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but .borders {border-width:1px !important} has no effect. Any other ideas?